# Check for application resuming from inactive as apposed to first starting?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios, multitasking

I have a NSTimer that I am stopping when my application resigns active, which I later restart when the application again becomes active. What I did not realise was that `applicationWillResignActive` would fire when my application first started (pretty obvious really). So what is happening is my NSTimer is incorrectly starting (when the application first starts). My question is, is there a way to check for the application resuming from inactive as apposed to it first starting?

```
- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application {
    // STOP CORE TIMER
    [[[self mapController] coreTimer] invalidate];
    [[self mapController] setCoreTimer:nil];
}
```

.

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
    // START CORE TIMER
    [[self mapController] setCoreTimer:[NSTimer 
        scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:ONE_SECOND 
                                target:[self mapController]   
                              selector:@selector(timerDisplay:) 
                              userInfo:nil 
                               repeats:YES]];
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is the [`applicationWillEnterForeground`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006786-CH3-SW21) which seems to only fire when the app comes back from the background. Just tested it, won't be called on launch.

> **Discussion**
>
> In iOS 4.0 and later, this method is
>   called as part of the transition from
>   the background to the active state.
>   You can use this method to undo many
>   of the changes you made to your
>   application upon entering the
>   background. The call to this method is
>   invariably followed by a call to the
>   applicationDidBecomeActive: method,
>   which then moves the application from
>   the inactive to the active state.

Comment: wish I knew this a while back.  I just used a check on a boolean in ApplicationDidBecomeActive to see if it was just started or not.

Comment: Much appreciated, one issue: I dealing with the user locking the iPhone (top button) and then unlocking it using the screen slider, in this case the app never gets into the background (well not quickly anyways), it just goes from applicationWillResignActive to applicationDidBecomeActive.

Comment: Well according to my tests `applicationWillResignActive` and `applicationDidBecomeActive` are called immediately when the user locks and unlocks the phone.

Comment: That is correct plus applicationDidBecomeActive is called at startup too, which is my problem. I think the answer in my case is to add a flag (as Jesse suggested) to record which state the application is in.

Comment: @fuzzygoat yes I think that's the way to go. I am out of any new ideas.